# Место в поисковиках

Tags: php

Добрый день, возможно ли сделать, чтоб при переходе на сайт с яндекса и гугла узнавался запрос, с которого пришли и место?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Comment: покажет страницу откуда пришли это ответ на первую часть вопроса.
А как узнать позицию

Comment: Никак не узнать. если только сразу не отправить этот же запрос в яндекс или гугл и спарсить всю страницу.

Comment: Очень жаль, пасиб